# Multiprocessing in Julia

Tags: julia

How to write a Julia code for a nested (for) loop which uses multi nodes for 1st (for) loop and later uses multi core from each node for the nested loop.

I want to run a multi node Julia code on cluster

Answer (score 0):

I think the best place to start is using [Distributed](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/distributed-computing/) where you can create tasks for each node and have each node use multiple cores via Julia's thread. Something like `pmap` should work perfectly for a parallel for loop.
Depending on your cluster there is also support for different job scheduler (pbs, slurm, ...) with [Cluster Managers.jl](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/ClusterManagers.jl)

Comment: I am using a cluster which uses slurm type Job. Here are my two loops I want to parallize sync Threads.threads for N=0:Nthetap
  theta_p[N+1] = thetap_min + N*(thetap_max-thetap_min)/Nthetap
  Ep1,P1=compute_max(eps,phi_cep,phi_p,theta_p[N+1],lamda,I,Ip,np,Y-1,NE_max)
  P_tem[N+1]=P1
  En[N+1]=Ep1
 end
    P_max,location=findmax(P_tem)
    theta_max=theta_p[location]
    E_max=En[location]
    return P_max,theta_max,E_max
 sync begin
   distributed for i in Inten
      I=i*10
   P_max,theta_max,E_max = find(eps,phi_cep,phi_p,lamda,I,Ip,np)
   Pz=sqrt(2*E_max)*cosd(theta_max)

Comment: You will need to define the inside of your for looop as a function with some arguments then you can pass the function and iterator `0:Nthetap` to `pmap` i.e as `pmap(myfunc, workerpool, 0:Nthetap)`. Your worker pool can be obtained from the CLusterManager for slurm